# Find $f(x)$ from $2f'(x)-3f'(1/x)=x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Find $f(x)$ given that $2f'(x)-3f'(1/x)=x$

Also, is it possible to do this without integration?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ supposed to be?

Answer (score 8):

Replace $ x $ by $1/x$, you will get two equations in two variables which here will be $f'(x) $ and $ f'(1/x)$
solve them to get $f'(x)$ and then use integration to get $f(x)$.

Comment: +1, cute. By that method $f(x)=-\frac{1}{5}(x^2+3\log(x))$.

Comment: Or $\ n f'(x)+mf'(1/x)=k\ x\ $ becomes $\ f(x)=\frac{k}{n^2-m^2}(\frac{n}{2}x^2-m\log(x))$.